# Pika Consumer as a Python Process (multiprocessing)

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pika

I am trying to use the example Pika Async consumer (http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html) as a multiprocessing process (by making the ExampleConsumer class subclass multiprocessing.Process).  However, I'm running into some issues with gracefully shutting down everything.

Let's say for example I have defined my procs as below:

```
for k, v in queues_callbacks.iteritems():
        proc = ExampleConsumer(queue, k, v, rabbit_user, rabbit_pw, rabbit_host, rabbit_port)
```

"queues_callbacks" is basically just a dictionary of exchange : callback_function (ideally I'd like to be able to connect to several exchanges with this architecture).

Then I do the normal python way of dealing with starting processes:

```
try:
        for proc in self.consumers:
               proc.start()
        for proc in self.consumers:
               proc.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for proc in self.consumers:
              proc.terminate()
              proc.join(1)
```

The issue is coming when I try to stop everything.  Let's say I've overriden the "terminate" method to call the consumer's "stop" method then continue on with the normal terminate of Process.  With this structure, I am getting some strange attribute errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/christopheralexander/PycharmProjects/new_bot/abstract_bot.py", line 154, in <module>
main()
File "/Users/christopheralexander/PycharmProjects/new_bot/abstract_bot.py", line 150, in main
mybot.start()
File "/Users/christopheralexander/PycharmProjects/new_bot/abstract_bot.py", line 71, in start
self.stop()
File "/Users/christopheralexander/PycharmProjects/new_bot/abstract_bot.py", line 53, in stop
self.__stop_consumers__()
File "/Users/christopheralexander/PycharmProjects/new_bot/abstract_bot.py", line 130, in __stop_consumers__
self.consumers[0].terminate()
File "/Users/christopheralexander/PycharmProjects/new_bot/rabbit_consumer.py", line 414, in terminate
self.stop()
File "/Users/christopheralexander/PycharmProjects/new_bot/rabbit_consumer.py", line 399, in stop
self._connection.ioloop.start()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ioloop'
```

It's as if these attributes somehow disappear at some point.  In the particular case above, _connection is initialized as None, but then gets set when the Consumer is started.  However, when the "stop" method is called, it has already reverted back to None (with nothing set to do so).  I'm also observing other strange behavior, such as times when it appears that things are getting called twice (even though "stop" is called once). Any ideas as to what is going on here, or is this not the proper way of architecting this?

Thanks!